# How does python threading.Timer determine elapsed time?

Tags: python, timer, python-3.4

I'm running some experiments in a virtual machine, which has its system time updated if its suspended. I want to know if I can suspend the virtual machine and not affect the timer. That is, does Timer use system time or wall time?

I've tried looking through the source code and got to `_thread.lock.acquire` before the code dips into C.

Below is my code. I delegate to a subprocess that outputs 'plans'. I keep collecting these plans until the optimal plan is found or the maximum allowed time has elapsed. The timer is used to terminate the process if time runs out (which is the expected state of affairs). I need to know that the `Timer` will not be effected by system time being updated as it will invalidate the experiment I'm running.

```
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, cwd=self.working_directory)
timer = Timer(float(self.planning_time), p.terminate)
timer.start()

plan = None
while True:
    try:
        plan = list(decode_plan_from_optic(self.decode(p.stdout), 
                    report_incomplete_plan=True))
    except IncompletePlanException:
        break
timer.cancel()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure python doesn't offer any guarantees, it simply uses the C-level system calls so you have to look at their documentation to see what do they do. (The `Timer` is implemented using a `Condition` object, which internally creates a `Lock` and calls its `acquire` method, so you have to check the gurantees of the system calls to acquire locks on your OS).

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks, I checked the source and discovered the answer in `thread_pthread.h`. It turns out python waits are dependent on system time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon examination of the python source code for *unix it systems, I found that python eventually delegates to `sem_timedwait` from `semaphore.h` or `pthread_cond_timedwait` from `pthread.h` depending on support. Either way, both functions take a `struct timespec` from `time.h` as an absolute time to wait till -- timespec is the number of seconds and nanoseconds since the epoch.

So on the face of it seems that waiting in python is dependent on system time -- meaning my program would be effected by a change in system time. However, `time.h` specifies the constant `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` and the function `clock_gettime`, if a monotonically increasing clock is required. Showing there is an ability to wait independently of system time. However, sadly python uses `gettimeofday` (marked as obsolete since 2008) which is affected by changes to system time.

In short, waiting in python on *unix systems is effected by changes to system time.